# Release version of KEIL project much slower than debug version on STM32F413 MCU, why?

Tags: debugging, release, keil, stm32f4, ppp

I have developed firmware on STM32F413 with STM32CubeMX using FreeRTOS. I have several tasks and PPP connection over Serial (PPPoS). I am using **KEIL IDE** for **debug** and **everything is OK in debug mode** and after debug without resetting MCU. **But when I powered off it and then power on again**, **operations were 8X slower** (sending data over UDP on PPPoS can be slow!). There is no error in data transferring, only the unexpected slowdown.

I have tested it with STM32CubeProgrammer too by flashing `.hex` file and running it with STM32CubeProgrammer, and everything is OK! After I power down and on again, the problem recurs.

I notice that in debug, KEIL uses object files. But I cannot understand what is different between the power-on MCU situation (booting time) vs. debug time.

How I can fix this problem?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I rechecked reset scenario and find that with longer reset signal everything be OK!

I increased nRST pin capacitor value and problem have been resolved.

STM32F413 datasheet recommends 100nF value for capacitor but it is not good in my case.

The only thing that I don't understand yet is that why with other codes I haven't this problem? and why in this case it works slowly (instead not completely wrong)?